# Malware Protection Live In System Tray

Tags: windows-10, malware, youtube

This program was installed without my knowledge when `YouTube Downloader` ask for update - it installed itself together with `YTD` bundle - namely `Malware Protection Live`.

I removed the program out from my computer but it leaves track in my `System tray`.

**`How do I suppose to clean my system tray from programs not installed?`**

[image: st]

Answer (score 1):

For starters, have you tried performing a [System Restore](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html) to a point in time prior to that install?

My typical best practices recommendation for eliminating PUP or malware is to download both [RKill](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/) and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)... they are both free.  Execute RKill first, terminate anything it finds, and then without rebooting your system perform a *Threat Scan* with Malwarebytes.

You should have a relatively clean bill of health after that but if the icon is still lingering, Shawn Brink over at Ten Forums has written numerous top-notch tutorials, and he also authored a [batch file available for download](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5662-notification-area-icons-reset-windows-10-a.html) that will reset the notification area icons cache.